# When use Spring WebClient, the connection is closed because of HttpClientOperations Received last HTTP packet

Tags: netty, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am using Spring WebClient to receive Server Sent Event from my server (published by Spring SSEEmitter). It work fine, however, for some reason, my server publish a string "0" in a new line periodically. When this happens, the WebClient will close the connection.

I dug in and turn on the Spring debug and found the following information:

```
     +--------------------...+
     |  0  1  2  3  4  5  ... |
     | 30 0d 0a 0d 0a     ...-|0....           |

[reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations:218] Received last HTTP packet
[reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient:71] - USER_EVENT: [Handler Terminated]
[reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler:218] - Disposing context reactor.ipc.netty.channel.PooledClientContextHandler@45a97ad8
[reactor.ipc.netty.channel.PooledClientContextHandler:218] - Releasing channel: 
[reactor.ipc.netty.resources.DefaultPoolResources:218] - Released, now 0 active connections
[reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient:71] - READ COMPLETE
[reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient:71] - READ COMPLETE
[reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient:71] - CLOSE
[reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient:71] - INACTIVE
[reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient:71] - UNREGISTERED
```

It is clear WebClient internally uses Netty HttpClient, and this client treats the string "0" as the "lastHttpMessage", and then close the connection.

My questions:

- Why Netty treats "0" as end of http connection.
- Is that possible to configure sth to modify this behavior.
- WebClient can only use Netty or something else can be plugged in? Seems not possible so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `"0"` you're seeing is something part of the HTTP spec - when servers are sending an HTTP chunked response, a chunk of size 0 means that the response is complete.

I don't think there's anything we can configure in Netty to change that, nor I don't think we should, since this is the expected behavior for HTTP.

Now I'd rather like to know why the server is sending that in the first place. It might be that your `Flux` on the server has reached its end and is sending the `onComplete` signal, terminating the response. There might be something in your server implementation that completes the stream.

You can try and find out what's happening in your server by adding `log` Reactor operators in your pipeline to see which part is sending that `onComplete` signal. If you've got a code snippet to show us, I think you could create another question, as this one is already quite useful for the Spring community and making it more complicated won't really help.

Spring Framework will support other client libraries with `WebClient` - for example, the Jetty client (see issue [SPR-15092](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15092). But I don't think using another client will solve this issue, as it's compliant with HTTP and not a client-specific behavior.

Comment: I agree your suggestion. Just one question: on server side, it is not Flux. Instead, it is the old SSEEmitter. On client side, if I use Jersey SSE client, for a reason I don't know, it can ignore the "0" and keep the connection alive. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: No idea unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

I found out if I use "repeat", the Flux will automatically reconnect when the connection is done. Sweet!

```
final Flux<Object> stream = WebClient
            .create("http://localhost:8080/ssp")
            .get().uri("/common/v1/eventstream")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(ServerSentEvent.class)
            .flatMap(e -> Mono.justOrEmpty(e.data()))
            .repeat();

    stream.subscribe(e -> System.out.println(e));
```